# JS IndexedDB closure/inner function

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I would like to understand why in this "loop" I cannot attach the key of element in an event with a closure/inner function. I know what happens with other loops like `for,while` ... I don't understand the real reason why in this situation this approach doesn't work.

Q: Why can I not pass the key directly?

```
item.transaction(["itens"], "readonly").objectStore("itens").openCursor()
                .onsuccess = function(e) {
                    var info = e.target.result;
                    if (info) {


                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        var h2 = document.createElement("h2");

                        img.src = "../imagens/misc/" + info.value.image;
                        h2.innerHTML = info.value.title;
                        div.appendChild(h2);


                        div.onclick = function() {
  //always the lasy key.
                           console.log(info.key);


                        };

                        div.appendChild(img);
                        box.appendChild(div);

                        info.continue();
                    }
                };
```

I know type of solution works...

```
bt.onclick = (function(index) {
        return function (){console.log('iterator: ' + index);}
    })(i);  

with ({ n: i }) {
bt.onclick = function(index) {
    console.log('iterator: ' + n);
};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example given, you're overwriting `div.onclick` for each iteration of the cursor.

What's going on might be clearer if you changed it to be:

```
console.log('overwriting onclick handler to log: ' + info.key);
div.onclick = function() {
  console.log(info.key);
};
```

Or instead, don't overwrite:

```
console.log('adding onclick listener to log: ' + info.key);
div.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(info.key);
});
```

These will behave differently but perhaps help you to understand what's going on.